# Datatype - Salesforce to Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud

What should Marketing Cloud data extension datatype be for source field coming from Salesforce that is Double, Precision=18, Scale=0.  Marketing Cloud data will be sent back to Salesforce.  Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

If your source field coming from Salesforce is Double, Precision=18, Scale=0 then in SFMC Data Extension you could use Decimal with size 18,0